# Basic recursive descent parser for the set of closed parentheses

Tags: c++, parsing, recursion

How do I make a recursive descent LL(1) parser (I'm using `C++`) for the following grammar:

```
S -> SS  
S -> (S)  
S -> epsilon
```

I've made an attempt using recursive functions, but I think it's completely wrong. I know that the rules need to be implemented in order, but how do I get the first rule to check for other instances of the first rule without going on an infinite loop? In my code I have it only check for subsequent rules.

My code:

```
bool rule1(tokenizer * tp){ // S -> SS
    return rule2(tp) && rule2(tp);
}

bool rule2(tokenizer * tp){ // S -> (S)
    bool returnVal = false;

    if(tp-> lookahead. front( ). type == tkn_LPAR){
        tokenizer tmpTknzr = &tp;       
        tp-> lookahead. pop_front( );
        if(tp-> lookahead. front( ). type == tkn_RPAR){ // S -> epsilon
            tp-> lookahead. pop_front( );
            returnVal = true;
        } else {
            if(evalS(tp) && tp-> lookahead. front( ). type == tkn_RPAR){
                tp-> lookahead. pop_front( );
                returnVal = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}

bool evalS(tokenizer * tp){ // evaluate S
    return rule1(tp) || rule2(tp);
}
```

Comment: If you generate your first and follow sets for the grammar then you can key off of the elements in your first sets to enter your productions and your follow sets to leave your productions. The code usually ends up pretty simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a top down parser based on a custom language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21650555/create-a-top-down-parser-based-on-a-custom-language)

Comment: Please do not re-ask your question, but edit the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your grammar is not LL(1) -- in fact it is ambiguous, which makes parsing much harder.  Try using an LL(1) grammar for parenthesis, like

```
S -> (S)S
S -> ε
```

Answer (score 1):

The 1 in LL(1) means that you must be able to select the current rule to expand by looking ahead at no more than 1 token.

With the grammar as you've written it, you cannot determine which rule to expand when you look at the first token.  If it's a `'('`, then you don't know if it's rule 2 or rule 1 where the first S expanded to an epsilon.  That's why you can get stuck in infinite recursion.

The trick is to transform your grammar into a form where each rule that can apply to non-terminal X begins with a distinct terminal.  Chris Dodd's answer showed one way to do that for your grammar.